# blank screen after re-starting launcher activity (failed binder transaction)

Tags: android

I have this really weird problem where my app sometimes shows a black screen when i try to re-launch it. This happens occasionally and i really can't find a solution after digging into my code for weeks!

This is how it happens:
I open my app, do some stuff and then i return to the home screen. After several hours, i relaunch my app and it opens just a blank screen (no ANR or whatsoever thrown!).
I've also put some log messages into the onCreate() and onResume() method, but they never show up.
The logcat shows me a lot of "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION" errors when this happens.
Other than various other threads, i am not passing any images or large objects through any Intent. A "TransactionTooLargeException" is NOT being thrown either.

So this is how my data/anr/traces.txt looks like (unfortunately, my app itself it not being "traced"):

http://www.xup.in/dl,19638443/traces.txt.

And this is my dumpsys.txt:

http://www.xup.in/dl,10520097/dumpsys.txt.

My testdevice where this happens: Samsung Galaxy S1 (android 2.3.6)

The blank screen doesn't seem to occur on my ICS phone (LG Optimus G)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Do you use AdMob SDK in your application? I solved this issue by downgrading version 6.4.1 back to 6.2.1...

Comment: Yes, i am actually using Admob 6.4.1! I will try out your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer and should have instead been posted as a comment.